# How do I return an exception?

Tags: python

I wrote a function that needs to do 3 checks and if one of the tests fails it should return an exception of type of LookupError, but it doesn't work.
(*verify_checksum is another function)

```
def check_datagram(datagram, src_comp, dst_app):
    try:
        src_comp==datagram[0:16]
    except LookupError:
        return "Mismatch in src_comp"
    try:
        dst_app==datagram[40:48]
    except LookupError:
        return "Mismatch in dst_app"
    try:
        verify_checksum(datagram)
    except False:
        return "Wrong checksum"
    return True
```

For example:

Input:

```
check_datagram("1111000000001111000011111111000001010101101010101111111111111111000000001111111100000000","0000111100001111", "11110000")
```

Expected output:

```
"Mismatch in dst_app"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def check_datagram(datagram, src_comp, dst_app):
    if src_comp != datagram[0:16]:
        raise LookupError("Mismatch in src_comp")
    if dst_app != datagram[40:48]:
        raise LookupError("Mismatch in dst_app")
    if not verify_checksum(datagram):
        raise LookupError("Wrong checksum")
    return True # redundant?
```

Comment: tnx! so I dont need to use "try"?

Comment: @user1816377: You don't. The idea is to do the verification and, if anything is wrong, to raise `LookupError`.

Comment: @user1816377 `try`/`except` are for catching errors -- `raise` is for raising errors.

Answer (score 0):

With construction from NPE's answer you should use try..except there where you'll use declared check_datagram() function.

```
#python3
try:
    check_datagram(a,b,c)
except LookupError as e:
    print(str(e))
```

That allow you to get message from raised error.